# Deserialize XML based on Attribute Value

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, deserialization

Using c# what's the best way to deserialize a paricular entry in the following XML. i.e. I would like to return all the values for the element attribute "ID" that equals "0001"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Record ID="0001">
       <Random1>string1</Random1>
       <Random2>string1</Random2>
       <Random3>string1</Random3>
       <Random4>string1</Random4>
    </Record>
    <Record ID="0002">
       <Random1>string1</Random1>
       <Random2>string1</Random2>
       <Random3>string1</Random3>
       <Random4>string1</Random4>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Hope that makes sense, apologise is the jargon I've used is incorrect still a newb.

Comment: Also the "Random1", etc... attribute names many change from client to client

Comment: Random1 is not an `attribute` its a childnode

Comment: You'd have better luck receiving quality answers if you include the C# code you've tried and explained how it's not meeting your expectations.  Providing your input XML is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private List<string> GetRecordChildrenList(string xmlPath, string recordID)
{
    var childNodes = new List<string>();
    var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
    var record = doc.Descendants("Record").FirstOrDefault(r => r.Attribute("ID").Value == recordID);
    if(record != null)
        childNodes = record.Descendants().Select(elm => elm.Value).ToList();
    return childNodes;
}
```

Call it like

```
var path = "~/App_Data/TestXML.xml";
var values = GetRecordChildrenList(path, "0001");
```

returns `string1, string2, string3, string4`